# AngularJS Controller not registered

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

I'm new using Angular with MVC Web Api but using VB instead of C#. I'm trying to make an SPA web site and I have some week trying to solve this problem. 
In my `app.js` I defined the routing to my views and the controllers I'm going to use in them

```
var goMessage = angular.module('goMessage', ['ngRoute', 'goMessage.controllers', 'goMessage.services', 'goMessage.directives']);

angular.module('goMessage.controllers', []);
angular.module('goMessage.services', []);
angular.module('goMessage.directives', []);

goMessage.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  //Vista Login
  $routeProvider.when('/login/inicio', {
    controller: 'loginController',
    controllerAs: 'lgCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'Home/Login'
  });

  //Vista Usuarios
  $routeProvider.when('/usuarios/lista', {
    controller: 'usuariosController',
    controllerAs: 'usCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'Home/Usuarios'
  });

  $routeProvider.when('/dashboard/inicio', {
    controller: 'dashboardController',
    controllerAs: 'dashCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'Home/Dashboard'
  });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

The `usuariosController.js` controller is working very well, its code is:

```
   angular.module('goMessage.controllers')
        .controller("usuariosController", ['$scope', '$http', 'ws', '$window', '$timeout', '$route',
            function ($scope, $http, ws, $window, $timeout, $route) {
                //Declaración de variables
                var me = this;
                //Ordenamiento por default
                this.ordenarPorColumna = 'UsuarioID';
                this.reverse = false;
                // More code...
            }
        ]);
```

And the `loginController.js` controller code is:

```
 angular.module('goMessage.controllers')
        .controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', 'ws', '$window', '$timeout', '$route',
            function ($scope, $http, ws, $window, $timeout, $route) {
                //Declaración de variables
                var me = this;

                this.myData = "Data$$$";
            }
        ]);
```

In the `Login.vbhtml` view I'm following the same pattern as the `Usuarios.vbhtml` view. I define my ng-app in the `_layout.vbhtml` and I don't define any controller inside any view.

The error I'm unable to solve is this:
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeEyG.png)

Look at the AngularJs Expression

As you can see, I've defined both controller using the same way but the only one that works is the `usuarios` one and any other controller I add doesn't work.

Here I show you the scripts loading order:
[Scripts Loading Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x17vB.png)

I'm using my local IIS and working in VS2012.
The angular JS version is 1.6.

Comment: Can you please look more into your code as the above mentioned code is working fine - http://plnkr.co/edit/1KKCa0rEaO2Cd00xwFbp?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for checking @swapnesh. I can see it works fine and I don't see why is not working on my machine. Do you think the problem is related to an IIS configuration?

Comment: If its related to IIS, even your first controller should not suppose to work

Comment: I think might be some very small code error is thr in code ..please check it once more or use and JS linting to catch errror

Comment: I'm sorry, I tested many times and I didn't find the mistake. I don't see how one controller is working and the other one isn't. Thanks @swapnesh

Comment: Try to mirror your code in Plnkr ..I guess it will be more easy to debug then

Comment: I changed my VS 2012 to VS 2017 and it starts to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To register the logic modules as `controller`, `filter` and etc..., you need to add this code in your `app.config`

```
var app = angular.module("App", []);

var config = function ($controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide) {

     app.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
     app.directive = $compileProvider.register;
     app.filter = $filterProvider.register;
     app.factory = $provide.factory;
     app.service = $provide.service;
     app.constant = $provide.constant;

     //your codes

}

config.$inject = ["$controllerProvider", "$compileProvider", "$filterProvider", "$provide"];
app.config(config);
```

**Why this happen?**

sometimes we don't need to add all of controllers in our main index which has `ng-view` or `ui-view` for that we should put our controller as lazyload to the `app.config` as you do this in your ***config***, because of that the main app for get the controllers need to register controllers and other modules.

Comment: I tried that but I'm still getting the same error, my controller is not registered. Could it be something related to the `RenderScripts`? Because I add the controller's link to the resource directly to the `_layout.vbhtml` and the error message disappear.

Comment: so i guess you didn't load your controller at all !! to make sure of load controller in chrome `F12 > Sources` left side check if it load or not

Comment: I did as you said and the controller is being loaded every time I refresh the page.

Comment: I solved it by changing my VS version from 2012 to 2017 Community. Thanks @Maher

Answer (score 0):

This issue might happen due to asynchronous loading of scripts. The script order might also be an issue. You can add a `console.log` at the beginning of loginController to check whether the component is loaded correctly.

Comment: I did it but nothing happened. The console.log was never executed because the controller remains unregistered.

Comment: How are you loading the `loginController.js`? It might be an issue with the loading order.

Comment: I edited the question and added an image of the scripts loading order. Every controller I have are after the `app.js`

Comment: I solved it by changing my VS version from 2012 to 2017 Community. Thanks @Sibin